# Which drawable assets are needed for tablets?

Tags: android, android-drawable, tablet

I'm still getting the following in the Play Store:

> **Design your app for tablets**

Your Production APK needs to meet the following criteria:

Your APK should include custom drawables assets for common tablet screen densities.

My list of drawable resources is:

```
./app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_media_stop.png     32x32
./app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_media_stop.png      48x48 
./app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_media_stop.png     64x64
./app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_media_stop.png     96x96
./app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png    48x48
./app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png    72x72 
./app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png     96x96
./app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png     144x144
./app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png     192x192
```

All images are 32-bit color.

Any idea why this is? I guess I'm missing something else?

Thanks for ideas so far but still not working... I now have the following (part duplicated) resources. It doesn't need qualified tablet layout does it? Docs don't show minimal setup to satisfy 7 and 10 inch tablet requirements afaics.

```
./app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_media_stop.png
./app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_media_stop.png
./app/src/main/res/drawable-sw600dp-hdpi/ic_media_stop.png
./app/src/main/res/drawable-sw600dp-mdpi/ic_media_stop.png
./app/src/main/res/drawable-sw600dp-xhdpi/ic_media_stop.png
./app/src/main/res/drawable-sw600dp-xxhdpi/ic_media_stop.png
./app/src/main/res/drawable-sw720dp-hdpi/ic_media_stop.png
./app/src/main/res/drawable-sw720dp-mdpi/ic_media_stop.png
./app/src/main/res/drawable-sw720dp-xhdpi/ic_media_stop.png
./app/src/main/res/drawable-sw720dp-xxhdpi/ic_media_stop.png
./app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_media_stop.png
./app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_media_stop.png
./app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
./app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
./app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png
./app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png
./app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png
```

Comment: See this link :<br> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157886/supporting-resources-for-tablets-and-mobiles

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I will look at this again over the next few days and update the question

Comment: Hi @Ewan . Did you solve the problem?

Comment: I've emailed Google Play support asking for help with this. I'll update anon, and check @Satyaveer's link above again when I have stamina

Comment: What was the fix for this?

Comment: @user2966445 No fix as yet

Answer (score 1):

Put your images in below folders for tablets .
For the 10-inch Tablets

res/drawable-xlarge-mdpi/

For 7-inch Tablets

res/drawable-large-mdpi/ or res/drawable-large

I hope this may solve your issue.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: No, I will look at this again over the next few days and update the question

Comment: Can someone confirm if the proposed solution actually works?